# problem with appending new uls

Tags: jquery, nested, set, append, live

I have da database with categories using nested sets.

i have a function, that should list me all the categories one level beneath a certain category.

when the document loads, the starting category is "1". this works. but when i click on a list item - to do the same with this items id as startingpoint, nothing happens. the data is passed to the document, but jquery isn't able to apend the list items to the created ul.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaSkript/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        ul.kategorien{ background: #FECA40; float: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="kategorien_auflisten" style="background-color: #ffffff;">

    </div>
    <div id="error"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function auflisten(start) {
    $("div#kategorien_auflisten").append("<ul class='kategorien' id='" + start + "'></ul>")

    jQuery.getJSON("Datenbankabfragen/kategorien_auflisten.php", {
        startknoten: start
    }, function(data) {
        if(data != "") {
            $.each(data, function(i,data){
                $("ul#"+start).append("<li class='' id='" + data.Kategorie_Nr + "'>" + data.Name + "</li>");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("div#error").text("Die Kategorien können leider nicht aufgelistet werden.");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    auflisten(1);
});

$("li").live("click", function() {
    auflisten($(this).attr("id"));
});
</script>
```

I hope anyone could help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see a couple of issues.

First, you're taking the ID from a `li` element:

```
$("li").live("click", function() {
    auflisten($(this).attr("id"));  // ID of the <li>
});
```

...passing it to `auflisten`:

```
function auflisten(start) {
```

...the assigning that ID to a `ul` element:

```
.append("<ul class='kategorien' id='" + start + "'></ul>")
```

So now it would seem that you have 2 elements with the same ID, which is invalid.

So it seems likely that when you try to select the new `ul` element from the DOM using that ID, the selection will fail:

```
 $("ul#"+start) // Trying to select based on a non-unique ID will cause problems.
```

---

Second, it seems that you're using numeric IDs. This is not valid in HTML4, and can cause similar selection problems.